# Can we change Vuejs global Property from child components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-resource

I am using vue-resource for http requests.

I set the authorization header in main.js file as:

```
Vue.http.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + Vue.auth.getToken()
```

But after login successfull I want to change its value from component without refreshing it.

I am trying to do this after getting loggedin in my Login.vue component:

```
this.$http.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + token
```

but still the Authoriztion header value remains unchanged. 
I just want the authorizstion header to be avaiable in all requests after getting logged in without refresh page.

Comment: Use vuex for such tasks.

Comment: How can I change global properties from vuex?. Can you give some kind of example please.

Comment: Dude.. use google. And it's 2018., every single website or anything related to development tells you to avoid using globals. You have million examples on this website how to use vuex to set variables that affect axios or vue-resource. Don't expect copy paste solution.